# USB Modem changes product ID on upgrading to 13.10

Tags: 13.04, networking, 13.10, usb-modem

Till yesterday, I was successfully using the Reliance Netconnect + USB modem (Vendor ID: 0x19d2, Product ID: 0xffe9).

This morning, I happened to upgrade to 13.10 and voila! The product ID has changed from ffe9 to fff5!

What did the Ubuntu guys do here? Any clues to solving this problem?